# Будет ли блокировка работать правильно?

Tags: c#, распараллеливание

У меня в коде много блокировок. Хотел немного сократить код и написал небольшой велосипед. Скажите пожалуйста будет ли это работать должным образом?

```
public static class LockingCall
{
    public static readonly object LockObject = new object();

    public static void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {
            action();
        }
    }

    public static T Invoke<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {
            return function();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос некорректен. Что такое "правильно"?

Comment: @vitidev ну то что действие или функция будут выполняться только в одном потоке. По моему это очевидно (то что я хотел этим сказать). Например если я хочу извлечь элемент из очереди которая используется несколькими потоками и я вместо громоздкого lock-а напишу так: LockingCall.Invoke(() => tasks.Dequeue())

Comment: ну оно будет работать как ожидаете. но сам подход в корне неверен. Так у вас общая блокировка на все вызовы подобного рода. По сути вы своими руками делаете так называемый GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). Блокировать нужно очередь в момент Dequeue

Comment: @vitidev не совсем понял что вы хотели этим сказать. Если так будет работать то почему бы не пользоваться этим более коротким вариантом? Про этот GIL тоже не слышал. А в чем будет разница то что я так заблокирую что обычным способом? Я даже подозреваю что оптимизатор развернет это в обычный lock.

Comment: Разница в том, что блокируя очередь на месте вы блокируете только эту очередь для тех, кто ее использует. А блокируя вашим способом вы блокируете любой метод вызванный с помощью вашего LockingCall.Invoke() общей блокировкой для всех вызовов. То есть у вас будет глобальная блокировка, где все методы которые попадут в ваш Invoke() просто станут в очередь, хотя у них и нет общих ресурсов за которые нужно бороться. Хотите улучшить - передавайте объект блокировки, LockingCall.Invoke(() => tasks.Dequeue(), tasks), тогда это будет метод хелпер с правильной блокировкой.

Comment: И не "в одном потоке" (это к контекстам синхронизации), а просто не параллельно.

Comment: Аа я просто только недавно освоил этот lock и не знал что передаваемый для блокировки объект так сильно влияет на это дело...

Comment: Для извлечения из очереди элемента, который используется несколькими потоками достаточно использовать `ConcurrentQueue` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lock блокирует только тех, у кого общий объект блокировки. Поэтому нужно избегать использования статических или слишком общих объектов для этого. Блокировка должна быть минимальной и значит объект блокировки должен затрагивать минимально необходимое количество держателей блокировки (если нужно то использовать именованные блокировки) и блокировать как можно меньшую секцию кода.

Также неправильно блокировать lock(this), потому что кто-то внешний может вызвать lock(обьект в котором lock(this) ) и получится неожиданная блокировка.

Ну и конечно по возможности использовать другие методы в виде потокобезопасных коллекций и async/await